# App closing after choosing image or taking picture

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the most recent version of the phonegap software inside Dreameweaver CS6. I took the starting example HTML file from the github website and imported it into DW. I then testing that app out and all worked with my location, map, etc.

However, i changed the code now to be able to either take a picture or choose a picture on my android phone and every time i do either/or it closes the app.

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      smallImage.src = imageData;
    }

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      largeImage.style.display = 'block';
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    function capturePhoto() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(getPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
    }

    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, allowEdit: false }); 
    }

    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And the config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap       = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id              = "com.xxxxxxxx.DKGApp"
    version         = "1.0.0">

    <name>DKG App</name>

    <description>
        An app that allows uploading their random images they take to our facebook website!
    </description>

    <author href    ="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com"  email       ="mail@xxxxxxxx.com">
        David
    </author>

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
</widget>
```

Am i missing something that is needed in order for this to work and not crash everytime?

Thanks!

Comment: do you see any error in the log (`adb logcat`)??

Comment: @dhaval: I do not know how to go about using adb logcat...?

Comment: if you are using eclipse just open `DDMS` perspective and you should see all the messages. if it is memory issue then follow what Simon mentioned below.

Comment: ok here is the log file... hope it can help! pastebin.com/fDxRMpYe

Comment: can you put your updated source in the pastebin?? also which android version are you using??

Comment: @dhaval: I am using Dreamweaver so i do not have the source (other than html, css and javascript i use to create the page). Android version 4.0.1

Comment: yes i mean the updated html/js file if you have done the changes as Simon mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an out of memory error. Please do not use DATA_URL. Returning a 3000x2000 pixel base64 encoded image will eat up all available memory in your app. Use FILE_URI instead.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of where to place the **FILE_URI** in my code above?

Comment: I've changed the code in the OP for **capturePhoto()** and **onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData)** but it still closes the app after clicking on the check mark to accept the captured image.

Comment: How do i do that when i am using Dreamweaver as my DEV environment?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I do not use DW.

Comment: I have the same problem, the only thing that solved it was to reduce reduce the image file to below 1000 pixels, but that's not a solution and I still can't find how to solve it properly and use a larger image.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. i fixed the issue using foreground-camera-plugin.

just go to this link and follow the steps.

### https://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/